# Join together two sparse columns within a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe with 3 columns- ID, Match, Match2 and I am looking to create a third column called Matchfinal. I need a function using numpy which looks at the Match column and sees if there is a True or a False. If it is True, it prints True in the Matchfinal column. If it is false, it goes to the Match2 columns and sees if there is a True in there. If Match 2 has a True, then it will write True in the Matchfinal column. If it see a false in both the Match and the Match2 column, it will write a False in the Matchfinal column.

```
Example of  dataframe:
ID     Match    Match 2   Matchfinal  
123    True     False     True  
1234   False    True      True
145    False    False     False           
158    False    True      True

The code i am currently using just writes whatever I have in the column Match. 
df['Matchfinal']= df.Match.combine_first(df['Match2'])
```

Comment: `df['Matchfinal'] = df.filter(like='Match').any(1)`  - is that what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a bit generic solution for various number of `Match*` columns:

```
In [51]: x
Out[51]:
     ID  Match Match2 Match3 Match4
0   123   True  False   True   True
1  1234  False   True  False   True
2   145  False  False  False  False
3   158  False   True  False  False

In [52]: x['Matchfinal'] = x.filter(like='Match').any(1)

In [53]: x
Out[53]:
     ID  Match Match2 Match3 Match4 Matchfinal
0   123   True  False   True   True       True
1  1234  False   True  False   True       True
2   145  False  False  False  False      False
3   158  False   True  False  False       True
```

Comment: Can you please explain what the `.any(1)` does. Thanks! :-)

Comment: @DmitryPolonskiy, `DataFrame.any(axis=1)` - returns `True` for those __rows__ where at least one value is `True`, otherwise it returns `False`

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
df['Matchfinal'] = np.where((df['Match']|df['Match 2']), True, False)
```

Comment: you don't even need `np.where()` - `df['Match'] | df['Match 2']` - returns True/False ;)

Comment: @VaishaliGarg Despite maybe having the same performance, it is completely superfluous :)

Answer (score 0):

```
df["MatchFinal"] = df.apply(lambda x: any(x), axis=1)
```

This would be my preferred way.